# How to clear previous data on the datagridview after an insert command on the table i.e. stop appending data?

Tags: c#

on my form load event i am selecting data from database and displaying it on the gridview.Then 
on insert button's click event i am inserting new data and immidiately displaying on the same datagridview but after insert, previous records are repeated on the gridview with new record.I want to stop this repeatation. Please give me the solution.

Comment: please show me your code , how did you load your data , how did you insert ?

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing rows if your datasource = null.
Which means you will not clear rows if some datasource is already assigned. Which is your case.

so you should do it like this. No need of if statement.

this.dataGridView.DataSource = null;

this.dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

or else you can use like

datagridview.DataSource = null;

bindingsource.DataSource = null;

bindingsource.Clear();